# Trying to get values of associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm have really lame question about PHP arrays, I'm trying to get all values of form[extras][], in this case they are 1,2,3,4, here is the output of print_r($array):

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[pickupDate][day]
            [value] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[pickupDate][month]
            [value] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[pickupTime][hour]
            [value] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[returnDate][day]
            [value] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[returnDate][month]
            [value] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[returnTime][hour]
            [value] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[car]
            [value] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[pickupAddress]
            [value] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[agency]
            [value] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[extras][]
            [value] => 1
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[extras][]
            [value] => 2
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[extras][]
            [value] => 3
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[extras][]
            [value] => 4
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [name] => form[specialPrice]
            [value] => 
        )

)
```

You can play with my data, by using this JSON string after converting it to PHP array like this:

```
$request = '[{"name":"form[pickupDate][day]","value":"1"},{"name":"form[pickupDate][month]","value":"8"},{"name":"form[pickupTime][hour]","value":"0"},{"name":"form[returnDate][day]","value":"1"},{"name":"form[returnDate][month]","value":"1"},{"name":"form[returnTime][hour]","value":"0"},{"name":"form[pickupAddress]","value":""},{"name":"form[agency]","value":"1"},{"name":"form[extras][]","value":"1"},{"name":"form[extras][]","value":"2"},{"name":"form[extras][]","value":"3"},{"name":"form[extras][]","value":"4"},{"name":"form[specialPrice]","value":""}]';
$array = json_decode($request,true);
```

I already tried with this, but it's resulting string(1) "4":

```
$result = array_column($array, null, 'name')['form[extras][]']['value'];
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Please show the expected result.

Comment: `foreach($arr as $subarr) { echo $subarr['value'] }`

Comment: `$result = array_column($array, 'value');`

Comment: Is `form[extras][]` a string or another array?

Comment: You'd have to use a while loop. Something like `while ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){ ...}` where `$count = count($your_array);` Then inside the `while` you should do a `foreach`. That ought to work.
EDIT: You should really post your php code. What you provide is printout of the result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a multidimensional array, this is an array composed by several arrays.

> ```
> array->[0]-[1]-[2]...  
>         |   |
>         |   [name]-[value]
>         | 
> array-> [name]-[value]
> ```

That's why you have to go through each element, for instance with this function (you have one already defined in PHP > 5.5.0):

```
function array_column($array, $value)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $element)
    {
        $result[] = $element[$value];
    }
    return $result[];
}
```

Edit: 
for getting the values of a subset of specific arrays based upon their name:

```
function getValuesOfTheArraysForExtras($array)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $element)
    {
        if($element['name']=='form[extras][]')
            $result[] = $element['value'];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I already tried with: $result = array_column($array, null, 'name')['form[extras][]']['value'];print_r($result);  In this case the result is: 4 (not 1,2,3,4)

Comment: $result = array_column($array, 'value');

Comment: get wrong result, all values of all element names: Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 
)

Comment: with the array you posted you would get this [1,10,0,1,1...]. What were you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting values only of form[extras][] - 1,2,3,4

Comment: I was looking for one-line code, but the function written by vivoconunxino do the work!